# How to get already opened camera to add flashlight in Android?

Tags: android, camera, boofcv

I'm using a 3-rd party library (boofCV) to work with a camera in Android . And they open the camera without a visible way of holding it:

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
manager.openCamera(cameraId, mStateCallback, null);
```

I need to add a flashlight with the camera but when I use this code:

```
cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true)
```

I got the error:

```
CameraAccessException: android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_IN_USE (4): setTorchMode:2122: Torch for camera "0" is not available due to an existing camera user.
```

And if I try to use this API < M code:

```
    val camera = Camera.open()
    val params = camera.parameters
    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)
    camera.setParameters(params)
    camera.startPreview()
```

I also get an error because of the camera is already opened:

```
E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Exception while stopping repeating: 
    android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_DISCONNECTED (2): checkPidStatus:2193: The camera device has been disconnected
```

So, how can I get the camera source to turn on/off the flashlight in this case?

**UPDATE**:
Hm, I even tried to rewrite the library's code and added

```
manager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
```

before

```
manager.openCamera(cameraId, mStateCallback, null);
```

But got only a short flash.

Comment: have you find solution?

Comment: For BoofCV I wrote the issue on its Github but after that switched to Zxing because of support of earlier Android versions (< M)